# I am getting error of conflict in asp.net MVC5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-5

I am getting error of conflict in asp.net MVC5

here is my model class of Form model

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public Guid FormId { get; set; }
        public Guid EntityBlockId { get; set; } // LinkToEntityBlockId
        public virtual EntityBlock EntityBlock { get; set; }
```

here is my model class of EntityBlock model

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public Guid EntityBlockId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Form> Form { get; set; }
```

and inserting the value like below:

```
FormStaticMethodsController formStaticMethodsControllerObj = new FormStaticMethodsController();

        Form form = new Form();
                    form.EntityBlockId = linkToBlockId;
    formStaticMethodsControllerObj.CreateForm(form);
```

method is:

```
 public Guid CreateForm(Form form)
            {
                db.Forms.Add(form);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return form.FormId;
            }
```

an the error is:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Form_dbo.EntityBlock_EntityBlockId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-Planetskool-20150303080110", table "dbo.EntityBlock", column 'EntityBlockId'.
The statement has been terminated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have `EntityBlockId`defined as the foreign key value for `EntityBlock`, you should link the `EntityBlock` property link with the field `EntityBlockId` by using the [ForeignKeyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute.aspx):

```
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid FormId { get; set; }
    public Guid EntityBlockId { get; set; } // LinkToEntityBlockId

    [ForeignKey("EntityBlockId")]
    public virtual EntityBlock EntityBlock { get; set; }
```